# Does a type just have 'linkage' other than internal/external linkage?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, linkage

3.5 [basic.link] paragraph 8 from *N4567* says that

> ... A type is said to have **linkage** if and only if:
>
> - it is a class or enumeration type that is named (or has a name for linkage purposes (7.1.3)) and the name has linkage; or
> - ...

which exclusively elaborates on linkage of types—one of the entities that a name can denote. However, it seems that **there is no information in this paragraph whether the linkage that a type shall have is internal or external**. Is it because there is no need to define it at all, or because it is already defined by other paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type either has linkage, or it doesn't. This paragraph is self-contained: the first half defines the notion of a type having linkage, and the second half describes restrictions on the use of types having no linkage. The notion of linkage of a type is not used anywhere else, as far as I can tell.